# Hide if cell is repeated anywhere

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a little help I work in a team that helps churches/mosques/temples etc develop projects which tackle poverty in their local area (or if they already have a project we help them be more effective) and every year we have a big job trying to get a sense of how much work we've done in different parts of the country.

I've made an excel workbook where we each have a sheet to record which groups we've worked with and where and how much time it took, and a wee macro makes that automatically alphabetise whenever it's updated. The first sheet combines all those individual pages, and this macro means that while my colleagues and I record every time we visit a local project, it only shows once on the main sheet

```
`Sub HideRows()
    BeginRow = 5
    EndRow = 400
    ChkCol = 2
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Cells((RowCnt - 1), ChkCol).Value 
Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt
End Sub`
```

I've then added a column with this formula

```
`SUMIF($B$1:$B$400,$B5, $E$5:$E$400)`
```

So basically the box at the end of each visible row shows the total time spent with that group because those rows are all still there they're just not visible.

Thought I was being pretty clever, but there's a problem - what if two of us are supporting the same church? because they're only alphabetized in our individual pages the "hide" macro doesn't cover it AND then to make matters worse the SUMIF function will count all of so we'd be double counting.

I can see two options for how to fix this and as it I'm struggling to find a way of doing either

Is it possible to use a Macro to hide any row that repeats data? currently the macro basically says

"Look at the group name directly above if you say the same thing hide yourself" and I've tried putting in a "Range" into that value check line and I'm doing something wrong because it's crashing the whole thing.

The other option would be to try to get the front page to alphabetise but I'm compiling the data from the individual sheets using another IF function

```
    =IF(ROW()-4<=$B$1,INDEX(Chris!B:B,ROW()),IF(ROW() 
<=$B$1+$C$1+4,INDEX(Pauline!B:B,ROW()-$B$1),IF(ROW() 
<=$B$1+$C$1+$D$1+4,INDEX(Alan!B:B,ROW()-$B$1-$C$1),"")))
```

And my reading tells me I can't alphabetise a column if what it displays is the result of a formula.

Does anyone have any tips on how I could fix this? Or other ways of tackling the problem? I know that the obvious answer is to use a Database but Microsoft Access doesn't come as standard with office anymore or whatever the reason is the basic answer is that would cost more money and I'm going to struggle getting people to learn a new programme.

Thanks to anyone who's read this far even if you don't have an answer for me.

Sample Data :

Here's an example of one of the table's for the worker

[image]

So the spreadhseet would take that and add it to this [image]

The front Page would turn that into

[image]

Comment: Hi can you please provide a sample data set for us to visualize what trouble are you having? 

There is definitely a way to this but it's better if you can at least provide a sample.

Comment: There's one unexplained "variable" *(not in programming sense)*  in your question. Upon receiving a duplicate, through what is determined which value (row) is hidden and which stays? The first one always stays and the rest gets hidden, or some other way? Also, if  I understood the background sauce correctly - if the two of you are supporting same church, shouldn't your "supports" be summarized together before hiding the rest? This would basically only show who supported it first, not for how much you supported it together

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 

Rawrplus - currently the first row always stays. Currently the first page doesn't say who worked with the group as the only purpose of recording things in this way is to try to quantify how much support so we know who's getting light touch help and who's getting more intensive support. 

BlitE - I'll add some sample data into the original post there appears to be a character limit on these comments. 

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your suggestions,

I solved this by adding another column into my consolidated table with the formula

```
           =COUNTIF($B$5:$B18, B18)
```

And then changing my VBA code to be

```
            Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
            BeginRow = 5
            EndRow = 400
            ChkCol =  7
            For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
                If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value >= 2 Then
                    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                      Else: Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
            Next RowCnt
             End Sub
```

Far from the most elegant way of doing things but it's working.